# Removing the current row from a table if the column value of the previous row is the same Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, partitioning, lag

I have a table as follows:

| ID | ACTIVE_STATUS | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 45 | TRUE | 2022-06-12 |
| 45 | TRUE | 2022-06-13 |
| 45 | FALSE | 2022-07-01 |
| 36 | TRUE | 2022-08-01 |
| 36 | FALSE | 2022-08-02 |
| 36 | FALSE | 2022-08-14 |
| 36 | TRUE | 2022-08-15 |
| 14 | TRUE | 2022-03-25 |
| 14 | TRUE | 2022-03-28 |
| 14 | TRUE | 2022-03-29 |

I would like to remove rows from the table where within each ID group, if the current `ACTIVE_STATUS` value is the same as the value in the previous row, then remove the current row (Basically I am keeping the rows where the `ACTIVE_STATUS` shows a change for each ID group).

For example for ID 45, the active status was TRUE on 2022-06-12 and stayed TRUE until it became FALSE on 2022-07-01 so I would delete the row where the status is TRUE for date 2022-06-13 since there is no change in status between that and the previous row.  I currently have the data ordered by DATE per ID group. I would like the output to look like

| ID | ACTIVE_STATUS | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 45 | TRUE | 2022-06-12 |
| 45 | FALSE | 2022-07-01 |
| 36 | TRUE | 2022-08-01 |
| 36 | FALSE | 2022-08-02 |
| 36 | TRUE | 2022-08-15 |
| 14 | TRUE | 2022-03-25 |

I currently have:

```
SELECT ID, ACTIVE_STATUS, DATE 
FROM MY_TABLE 
GROUP BY ID, ACTIVE_STATUS, DATE   
ORDER BY DATE;
```

But I am not sure how to use `lag()` to achieve this or a partition? Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Using [CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/conditional_change_event.html) windowed function:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *,     
    CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT(ACTIVE_STATUS != 
                           LAG(ACTIVE_STATUS) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DATE)) 
    OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DATE) AS con_true_event
  FROM tab
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID, con_true_event ORDER BY DATE) = 1
ORDER BY ID, DATE;
```

---

Sample data:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tab(ID INT, 
                            ACTIVE_STATUS BOOLEAN,
                            DATE DATE)
AS
          SELECT 45,    TRUE    ,'2022-06-12'
UNION ALL SELECT 45,    TRUE    ,'2022-06-13'
UNION ALL SELECT 45,    FALSE   ,'2022-07-01'
UNION ALL SELECT 36,    TRUE    ,'2022-08-01'
UNION ALL SELECT 36,    FALSE   ,'2022-08-02'
UNION ALL SELECT 36,    FALSE   ,'2022-08-14'
UNION ALL SELECT 36,    TRUE    ,'2022-08-15'
UNION ALL SELECT 14,    TRUE    ,'2022-03-25'
UNION ALL SELECT 14,    TRUE    ,'2022-03-28'
UNION ALL SELECT 14,    TRUE    ,'2022-03-29';
```

Output:

[image]

Before filtering:

**[image: strong text]**

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you would use `lag`. You can keep the `lag` in the `select` to see what it's doing. `Qualify` is to `Window Function` what `Having` is to `Group By`.

```
select *
from your_table
qualify lag(active_status) over(partition by id order by date) <> active_status or
        lag(active_status) over(partition by id order by date) is null
```

If your team is familiar with null-safe equality operators, you could use `is distinct from` and simplify that to

```
select *
from your_table
qualify lag(active_status) over(partition by id order by date) is distinct from active_status
```

Comment: This approach could be further simplified just to: `qualify lag(active_status) over(partition by id order by date) is distinct from active_status`